# How to check AWS Lambda last modified time stamp?

Tags: aws-lambda

My Lambda gets modified by other people with access.
How to check if my Lambda got modified after I changed it?
Is there a timestamp to see the last modified time or history?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the AWS Lambda UI you can look under `Qualifiers` `Versions` and view all the versions and the time of deployment.

If you want to do this via the CLI you can get the info of all versions via:
`aws lambda list-versions-by-function --function-name carrierint-shp-crt-integrtr-gtwy-acceptance-api --region us-east-1` .

If you want specific info about the last version install the `jq` program (`brew install jq`). Execute this command to get info of the latest version of your function:
`aws lambda list-versions-by-function --function-name carrierint-shp-crt-integrtr-gtwy-acceptance-api --region eu-west-1 | jq -r "(.Versions)[-1]`

If you only want the `lastModifiedDate` execute:
`aws lambda list-versions-by-function --function-name carrierint-shp-crt-integrtr-gtwy-acceptance-api --region eu-west-1 | jq -r "(.Versions)[-1] | .LastModified"`

Answer (score 1):

aws-cli

```
aws lambda list-versions-by-function --function-name lambda-function-name
```

This will list all versions with LastModified field